# How to print the predecessor of the nodes while implementing the BFS

Tags: c++, algorithm, breadth-first-search

this is the code for BFS and it works well we have to find the path from 0,0 to 2,3 (just an example case) but the thing is that the output of this code resembles flood fill algorithm and we dont get the actual predecessors of the nodes

```
//S->start
//E->end

S 0 0 0
|   
1-1-1-1
|   | |
1 0 1-E
|   | |
1-1-1-1

#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <utility>

//Infinity
#define INF 1000000

using namespace std;

int distances[4][4] = {
  {0,INF,INF,INF},
  {INF,INF,INF,INF},
  {INF,INF,INF,INF},
  {INF,INF,INF,INF},
};
int matrix[4][4] = {
  {1,0,0,0},
  {1,1,1,1},
  {1,0,1,1},
  {1,1,1,1}
};

void BFS()
{
  queue< pair<int,int> > queue;
  //Add the first node
  queue.push(make_pair(0,0));

  while(!queue.empty())
  {
    //cout << "here" << '\n';
    pair<int,int> cur = queue.front();
    queue.pop();
    //Check adjacent nodes
    if(cur.first-1 > 0)
    {
      if((distances[cur.first-1][cur.second] == INF) && (matrix[cur.first-1][cur.second] == 1))
      {
        distances[cur.first-1][cur.second] = distances[cur.first][cur.second]+1;
        queue.push(make_pair(cur.first-1,cur.second));
      }
    }
    if(cur.first+1 < 4)
    {
      if(distances[cur.first+1][cur.second] == INF && (matrix[cur.first+1][cur.second] == 1))
      {
        distances[cur.first+1][cur.second] = distances[cur.first][cur.second]+1;
        queue.push(make_pair(cur.first+1,cur.second));
      }
    }
    if(cur.second-1 > 0)
    {
      if((distances[cur.first][cur.second-1] == INF) && (matrix[cur.first][cur.second-1] == 1))
      {
        distances[cur.first][cur.second-1] = distances[cur.first][cur.second]+1;
        queue.push(make_pair(cur.first,cur.second-1));
      }
    }
    if(cur.second+1 < 4)
    {
      if((distances[cur.first][cur.second+1] == INF) && (matrix[cur.first][cur.second+1] == 1))
      {
        distances[cur.first][cur.second+1] = distances[cur.first][cur.second]+1;
        queue.push(make_pair(cur.first,cur.second+1));
      }
    }
  }

}


int main()
{
  BFS();
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
      if(distances[i][j] != INF)
        cout << distances[i][j] << ' ';
      else
        cout << "X" << ' ';
    }
    cout << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

so basically i want to print the parent of node from (2,3) to (0,0). so can you guys suggest how can i do that.

Comment: So how about a vector which is passed along with the function parameters to store the path?

Comment: 'bfs(vector)' ?? and declare the vector as 'pair<int,int>  vector'? but still we need a stack to store all the coordinates of the the path

Answer (score 1):

Create an auxiliary matrix of the same size as the input, and for each point in the matrix, store which was the point from which you visited it. So when you reach the destination, you can traverse the auxiliary matrix from the destination to find the path used.

Comment: I'm currently in a hurry. Raise any doubts you have in the comments, and I'll address them and improve the answer later on.

Comment: so can you suggest a pseudo code for it?  i guess i have to write the code in this 'if(cur.first-1>0)' and the rest of the ifs in the function BFS()

Answer (score 0):

Here is a java code that stores parents (predecessor) of each node

```
void bfs(int source){
    List<Integer> nodes = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    int i, element;
    visited[source] = source;
    queue.add(source);
    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
        element = queue.remove();
        i = element;
        nodes.add(element);
        List<Integer> iList = getEdge(i); // returns adjacent nodes
        int x = 0; 
        while(x < iList.size()){ // go through the nodes
            int index = iList.get(x);
            if(visited[index] == -1){ // if they have not been visited
                queue.add(index); // add to queue
                visited[index] = i; // add predecessor 
            }
            x++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(visited));

}

visited = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 5, 5, 6, 7]
```